# How does OAuth work?

Tags: algorithm, authentication, oauth

I do not mean how is it implemented, but rather **what steps should user pass**?

I'm working with Photobucket now and I found in its docs that I should generate a new token for every request, because the token can expire in a certain (but secret) period of time.

How does this generation work? Do I need a separate request for generating a token?

Comment: possible repeat- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390881/how-does-twitters-oauth-system-work

Answer (score -1):

You can have a log in button, and when a user clicks on it you would make an ajax request to get a new oauth access token and then generate the oauth url based on that token.

Then after the user authenticates they will be redirected to a callback URL that you must specify from within your account settings.